# Salesforce Web to lead

Tags: apex-email-service, email-alert, web2lead

We have a web to lead form setup. The people that enter these leads are NOT SFDC users. Part of the form requires them to enter their name and email. It also makes them pick from a list of sales reps. These sales reps become the lead owner. They want the person who entered the lead (not the lead owner) and the territory manager to be emailed every time the lead status changes (after the original lead was created). Can this be done? Would this need to be done using trigger?

Comment: How is the "territory manager" defined?

Answer (score 0):

One way - if the guys who enter the leads are few in number, we could add them as contacts in you SFDC app and then create a trigger to email these contacts

Better way - create a custom object with profiles of these guys who enter the leads. create a lookup in lead to this custom object. once linked your job is done, u can now create a workflow rule or a trigger

Answer (score 0):

You can create a workflow rule that fires on ISCHANGED(Status) which fires an email alert that sends to an email address field - that would be the email address field with the non SFDC user's email address.

That will email the non SFDC users.

I need to know how you identify your territory managers to understand if they can be emailed via workflow too - if not it might have to be a trigger. More info please :)